# How to use struct that is imported from another package

Tags: struct, go, import, undefined

Well, I have my struct **Player** in package **Player**

```
package Player

type Player struct {
    name         string
    speciality   string
}
```

And I have my **main function** in package **main**

```
package main

import "pack/Player"   

func main() {   
   var player Player.Player
   fmt.Print(player.name)
}
```

But after I compile it I get

> player.name undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method
>   name)

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to [export](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields of your structure in order for them to be accessible by having them start with upper case characters:

```
type Player struct {
    Name         string
    Speciality   string
}
```